# Provide different build configurations / flavors (development, production)

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app, I have a configuration like this:

```
api_url = https://api.poemhub.top
```

the problem is, in different environment the api url is different, when in develop, the api should look like this :

```
api_url = https://dev-api.poemhub.top
```

in test env:

```
api_url = https://beta-api.poemhub.top
```

in production environment:

```
api_url = https://api.poemhub.top
```

also other config different in different places, so what is the best way to treat this config in different environment? I have read a solution to define different `main.dart` and run build command like this:

```
flutter build apk -t lib/main_develop.dart
```

Comment: I think if you can check the apk type then you can change the env according to the apk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to go with [flutter flavors](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors). This feature does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

as an option
you can put this code somewhere

```
const APP_ENV = String.fromEnvironment('APP_ENV');
```

and build project with parameter DEV or PROD for example
`flutter build apk -t lib/main_develop.dart --dart-define=APP_ENV=DEV`

extended example

```
enum AppEnvironment { DEV, PROD, MOCK }

class EnvironmentConfig {
  static const APP_ENV = String.fromEnvironment('APP_ENV');
  static const LOG = String.fromEnvironment('LOG');

  AppEnvironment get appEnvironment => APP_ENV.isEmpty ? AppEnvironment.MOCK
      : AppEnvironment.values.firstWhere((e) => e.toString() == 'AppEnvironment.' + APP_ENV);

  String get baseUrl => appEnvironment == AppEnvironment.DEV ? 'https://some dev url'
      : appEnvironment == AppEnvironment.PROD ? 'https://some url'
      : 'https://mock';

}
```

and then

```
if (EnvironmentConfig().appEnvironment == AppEnvironment.DEV) {
   // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to [flutter flavors](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavor) suggested by @Pavlo Ostasha you can use [flutter flavorizr](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr)

1. In your `pubspecs.yaml` add

   ```
   dependencies: flutter_flavorizr: ^1.0.11
   ```
2. Install packages with

   ```
   flutter pub get
   ```
3. In your dart code use:

   ```
   import 'package:flutter_flavorizr/flutter_flavorizr.dart';
   ```

4. In your `pubspecs.yaml` define your `flavors`, for example `test` and `production` like below:

```yaml
flavorizr:
  app:
    android:
      flavorDimensions: "environment"
    ios:
    
flavors:
    test:
      app:
        name: "Your app - test"

      android:
        applicationId: "com.yourcompany.appid.dev"

      ios:
        bundleId: "com.yourcompany.appid.dev"

    production:
      app:
        name: "Your app"

      android:
        applicationId: "com.yourcompany.appid"
      ios:
        bundleId: "com.yourcompany.appid"
```

5. In the generated `lib/flavors.dart` file, define your `getter` for the api url

```dart
enum Flavor {
  TEST,
  PRODUCTION,
}

class F {
  static Flavor appFlavor;

  static String get apiUrl{
    switch (appFlavor) {
      case Flavor.TEST:
        return 'http://www.api-test.com';
      case Flavor.PRODUCTION:
        return 'http://www.api.com';
      default:
        return 'http://www.api.com';
    }
  }
}
```

6. In your code do

```dart
import 'package:app/flavors.dart';

class YourApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const YourApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  var apiUrl = F.apiUrl; // from flavors.dart
}
```